# Passing a struct to multiple other functions

Tags: c, struct

I'm relatively new to programming and I am having some issues passing my struct to other functions. Here is what my actual code looks like:

```
typedef struct Memcheck {

char *memoryAdd;
char *file;
int line;

struct Memcheck_struct *next;

} Memcheck;

char *strdup2( char *str )
{
  char *new;
  new = malloc( strlen(str)+1 );
  if (new)
    strcpy( new, str );
  return new;
}

/*Allocate memory for a ptr, and add it to the top of the linked list*/
void *memcheck_malloc(size_t size, char *file, int line){

Memcheck * new_memoryCheck = NULL;
Memcheck * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(Memcheck));
new_memoryCheck = malloc(sizeof(Memcheck));


new_memoryCheck->memoryAdd = malloc(sizeof(new_memoryCheck->memoryAdd));
new_memoryCheck->file = malloc(sizeof(new_memoryCheck->file));
new_memoryCheck->file = strdup2(file);
new_memoryCheck->line = line;
new_memoryCheck->next = head;


return new_memoryCheck;
}

/*Prints the error messages*/
void printList(Memcheck *new_memoryCheck) {

Memcheck * head = NULL;
Memcheck * current = head;
head = malloc(sizeof(Memcheck));
current = malloc(sizeof(Memcheck));

printf("new_mem file: %s\n", new_memoryCheck->file);
printf("current file: %s\n", current->file);

while (current != NULL) {
    printf("in loop\n");
printf("memcheck error:  memory address %p which was allocated in file \"%s\", line %d, was never freed\n", current, current->file, current->line);
current = current->next;
}
}

int memcheck_main(Memcheck new_memoryCheck){

printf("newmem file: %s\n", new_memoryCheck.file);
printf("Entering printList\n"); 
printList(&new_memoryCheck);

return 0;
}
```

I have strdup2 because apparently ansi doesn't have stdrup.

I know to use pass by reference to some degree but I'm not exactly sure where to use the `*` and `&` operators

Comment: The function `assignValues()` is causing memory leak and looks weird. Please describe what you want to do.

Comment: assignValues() is suppose to do the following: Allocate memory for a pointer, and add it to the top of a linked list.

Comment: Ah, you create a new member and throw it away in the function `assignValues`. The first thing to do is to return the created member.

Comment: After that I still have the same issue of having NULL as the values within new_node

Comment: Where is the linked list? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You don't show how you hook the allocated memory into the list.  The second `malloc()` is almost certainly wrong; you need to allocate enough space for the string (`strlen(file)+1` probably), and you certainly shouldn't use the pointer assignment instead of a string copy.  Consider `strdup()`.  You either need to return the pointer to the allocated node so external code can hook it into the list, or you need to pass the pointer to the list into the function and return the new head of the list, or you need to pass a pointer to a pointer into the function and assign the new head to that..

Comment: I'd expect `new_node->item = malloc(sizeof(new_node->item));` --> `new_node->item = malloc(sizeof *(new_node->item));`  (Add *)

Comment: Note that there are a lot of C questions about linked lists on SO.  Indeed, a search with '`[c] [linked-list] is:q`' returns over 3,000 (nearly 4,000) questions.

Comment: Should `char *memoryAdd;` be `void *memoryAdd;` (or perhaps `void *memoryAddr;` or `void *memoryAddress;` or `void *address;`).  The pointer is big enough to store a pointer; you don't need to allocate it.  If the `char *file;` is a file name (from `__FILE__` in a macro), then it is a constant and you don't need to duplicate it.  In fact, for both those pointers, you can simply assign the argument pointers to the allocated memory.   And then you don't need `strdup2()` — you're right, [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) is a POSIX function.

Comment: Also, don't you need to store the size in the structure somewhere?  And you have `typedef struct Memcheck { … struct Memcheck_struct *next; } Memcheck;` — the pointer in the structure doesn't point to another structure of the same type.  You don't show a `struct Memcheck_struct`, but you've just announced that it exists somewhere and you plan to define it before you need to dereference it.  Meanwhile, you can store pointers to it without problem.

Comment: Your right I've changed the declaration of `Memcheck_struct *next` to just `Memcheck *next`

Comment: When I am attempting to pass `new_memoryCheck` to my printList I lose the values within `new_memoryCheck` is that because I'm not passing the structure correctly?

Comment: That doesn't work; `Memcheck` isn't a type name until after the semicolon at the end of the `typedef`.  You either need `typedef struct Memcheck Memcheck;` before and `struct Memcheck { … Memcheck *next; };` or you need to use `struct Memcheck *next;` in the structure (the type `struct Memcheck` is known about at the `{`, though it isn't complete until the `}`.

Comment: So just create a new struct that holds `Memcheck *next` within it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you are writing a surrogate for `malloc()` that records which memory was allocated where, you probably need code similar to:

```
typedef struct Memcheck Memcheck;

struct Memcheck
{
    void       *data;
    size_t      size;
    const char *file;
    int         line;
    Memcheck   *next;
};

static Memcheck *memcheck_list = 0;

/* Allocate memory and record the allocation in the linked list */
void *memcheck_malloc(size_t size, const char *file, int line)
{
    Memcheck *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    void *data = malloc(size);
    if (node == 0 || data == 0)
    {
        free(node);
        free(data);
        return 0;
    }
    node->data = data;
    node->size = size;
    node->file = file;
    node->line = line;
    node->next = memcheck_list;
    memcheck_list = node;
    return data;
}
```

Note that if either (or both) memory allocations fails, the memory is all freed before returning.  Using `free()` on a null (`0`) pointer is a no-op.  Thus the clean-up is safe.  The information can simply be copied into the structure as shown; no need for extra memory allocations for the file name, for example, as long as you pass `__FILE__` to the function (which is a string literal, and therefore has a lifetime as long as the rest of the program).

Comment: So then I should only have to call `data` to use it in the other functions? Thanks for the answer too!!

Comment: You can use `#define MALLOC(size) memcheck_malloc(size, __FILE__, __LINE__)` and invoke: `char *str = MALLOC(sizeof("Help!"));` etc.  This will record the successful allocation in the `memcheck_list`, and you can use the resulting memory just as if you'd written `char *str = malloc(sizeof("Help!"));`.  I've ignored some details like "you'd need a header to declare `memcheck_malloc()` — and presumably `memcheck_realloc()`, `memcheck_free()`, `memcheck_calloc()` and so on.  However, that header would probably not expose the structure at all.  You'd provide functions to examine the list, too.

Comment: I do have a header file that defines all my functions and what not,  probably should have said that earlier. I still don't entirely understand how to pass the data to other functions tho.

Comment: You'd probably need to record which operation you just dealt with, too.  The `memcheck_free()` would need to match one of the allocations, and `memcheck_realloc()` would change the size and maybe the memory address too (and the file and line number info) for an entry already in the list.  `memcheck_calloc()` is basically the same as `memcheck_malloc()`, at least as far as records keeping is concerned, once you've multiplied the two sizes to produce an overall size.  So, there's a bit of work left to do.

Comment: You treat `memcheck_malloc()` as a surrogate (substitute) for `malloc()`.  You use the pointer it returns just as you would use a pointer returned by `malloc()`.  If you're not sure about using `malloc()`, that's a separate problem — you probably need to resolve that before trying to wrap it.

Comment: Yeah that is basically the rest of what I have to do.

Comment: I think I understand malloc. It just allocates for `size bytes` then returns a pointer to the allocated memory

Comment: There is a book, [Writing Solid Code](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1556155514/), that covers this sort of stuff in detail.  There are those who excoriate the book; I think it is quite a useful read, though it has to be recognized as being written soon after the original standard was released (1993), so it has some slightly archaic attitudes to what we now take for granted.  If you can find a copy in a library, it might be worth a read.  The appendices include some memory checking allocation code not a million miles removed from what's under discussion here.